# Limits in functor categories can be computed pointwise

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]$ denote the category of functors $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}.$

My notes say that if $\mathcal{D}$ has limits of shape $I$, then the composite $$[I, [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]] \cong [\mathcal{C},[I,\mathcal{D}]] \to [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]$$ is the same as the limit functor, where the right arrow comes from the limit functor $[I,\mathcal{D}] \to \mathcal{D}.$

I understand this statement, and the proof, but I'm having a hard time grasping why this means we can compute limits pointwise (or even what this means in the first place). Does it mean that:

Suppose $F$ is a functor $I \to [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}].$ We want to calculate $\lim_I{F}.$ First, change $F$ to a functor $G \colon \mathcal{C} \to [I, \mathcal{D}]$ by defining $G(x)(i) = F(i)(x)$ for $i \in I$ and $x\in \mathcal{C}.$ Then compose this with the functor $\lim_I \colon [I,\mathcal{D}] \to \mathcal{D}.$ So when we say "pointwise", do we mean that $$\lim_I{F}(x) = \lim_I(Gx)?$$

Comment: Yeah. That's basically it.

Comment: Shouldn't the left hand side of your last line read $(lim_I F)(x)$?

Comment: @gen that is actually what I meant, but in retrospect, your notation is definitely clearer

Comment: @DerekElkins, could you please explain how the isomorphism $[I, [C, D]] \sim [C, [I, D]]$ works?

Comment: @DerekElkins, OK I don't think this correspondence can be described concisely. If $\theta: I \rightarrow [C, D]$ then define $\hat{\theta}: C \rightarrow [I, D]$ by $\hat{\theta}(c) := \theta_c$ where $\theta_c$ is defined to take $i \mapsto \theta(i)(c)$ and $(f: i\rightarrow j) \mapsto \theta(f: i \rightarrow j)_c$ -- where $\theta(f)_c: \theta(i)(c) \rightarrow \theta(j)(c)$ is the morphism that's a component of the natural transformation $\theta(f): \theta(i) \Rightarrow \theta(j)$... Is this correct? Also this is self-inverse $\hat{\hat{\theta}} = \theta$...

Comment: @gen It's just uncurrying, swapping, and currying, i.e. $[I,[C,D]]\cong[I\times C,D]\cong[C\times I,D]\cong[C,[I,D]]$. It's the functor analogue of F(g)(i)(c)=g(c)(i)$.